# Tables aren't in order in itemize

Tags: tables, itemize

Good evening

Why is result so wrong? What is wrong? Tables aren't in order and the black marks aren't on the right place.

Thank you for help.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english,slovak]{babel}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[a6paper, top=10mm, left=10mm, right=10mm,    
bottom=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\catcode`\-=12
\sloppy

%************************************************************
\newpage
%************************************************************
\section*{\foreignlanguage{slovak}{Číslovky}}

\begin{itemize}
  \item ak je \textit{číslovka s podstatným menom} je \textit{jeden prízvuk}, na prvej slabike. Ak číslovka stojí na \textit{konci vety} bez podstatného mena, \textit{prízvuk} je na {\sffamily -teen}. 

  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    {\sffamily She is \textbf{fifteen}.}   & {\sffamily \textbf{Fifteen} players play football.}\\ 
    \textsl{[\textipa{fIf.\textprimstress ti:n}]}         & \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress fIf.ti:n}]} \\ 
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}


\item 

  \begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{rllrl}
    \toprule
    { $1$} & {\sffamily one}   & { \textsl{[\textipa{w2n}]}          }                   & $1$ \\
    { $2$} & {\sffamily two}   & { \textsl{[\textipa{tu:}]} }                            & $2$  \\  
    { $3$} & {\sffamily three} & { \textsl{[\textipa{Tri:}]}                           } & $3$  \\
    { $4$} & {\sffamily four}  & { \textsl{[\textipa{fO:\super r}]}                    } & $4$  \\
    { $5$} & {\sffamily five}  & { \textsl{[\textipa{faIv}]}                           } & $5$   \\
    { $6$} & {\sffamily six}   & { \textsl{[\textipa{sIks}]}                          }  & $6$   \\
    { $7$} & {\sffamily seven} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress sev.@n}]} }         & $7$   \\
    { $8$} & {\sffamily eight} & { \textsl{[\textipa{eIt}]}                           }  & $8$    \\
    { $9$} & {\sffamily nine}  & { \textsl{[\textipa{naIn}]}                          }  & $9$   \\
   { $10$} & {\sffamily ten}   & { \textsl{[\textipa{ten}]}                           }  & $10$  \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table} 

\item   

  \begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{rllrl}
    \toprule    
    { $11$} & {\sffamily eleven}    & { \textsl{[\textipa{I\textprimstress lev.@n}]}                    }        & $11$ \\
    { $12$} & {\sffamily twelve}    & { \textsl{[\textipa{twelv}]}                                             } & $12$ \\  
    { $13$} & {\sffamily thirteen}  & { \textsl{[\textipa{T3:\textprimstress ti:.n}]}                          } & $13$ \\
    { $14$} & {\sffamily fourteen}  & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textsecstress fO:\textprimstress ti:.n}]}           } & $14$  \\
    { $15$} & {\sffamily fifteen}   & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textsecstress fIf\textprimstress ti:n}]}            } & $15$ \\
    { $16$} & {\sffamily sixteen}   & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textsecstress sIks\textprimstress ti:n}]}           } & $16$  \\
    { $17$} & {\sffamily seventeen} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textsecstress sev.\super @n\textprimstress ti:n}]}  } & $17$  \\
    { $18$} & {\sffamily eighteen}  & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textsecstress eI\textprimstress ti:n}]}              } & $18$  \\
    { $19$} & {\sffamily nineteen}  & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textsecstress naIn\textprimstress ti:n}]}           } & $19$  \\
    { $20$} & {\sffamily twenty}    & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress twen.ti}]}                          }  & $20$  \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table} 

  \item 
  \begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{rllr}
    \toprule  
    { $30$} & {\sffamily thirty}    & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress T3:.ti}]}           }& $30$  \\
    { $40$} & {\sffamily forty}     & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress fO:.ti}]}           }& $40$  \\   
    { $50$} & {\sffamily fifty}     & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress fIf.ti}]}           }& $50$  \\
    { $60$} & {\sffamily sixty}     & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress sIk.sti}]}          }& $60$  \\
    { $70$} & {\sffamily seventy}   & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress sev.@n.ti}]}}& $70$   \\
    { $80$} & {\sffamily eighty}    & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress eI.ti}]}            }& $80$   \\
    { $90$} & {\sffamily ninety}    & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress naIn.ti}]}          }& $90$   \\
   { $100$} & {\sffamily hundred}   & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress h2n.dr@d}]}           }& $100$   \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table}  

\item  

  \scalebox{0.8}{
  \begin{tabular}{rlrlrl}
    \toprule    
    $1$  & {jeden    }  &       $11$  &    { jedenásť }   & $30$    &{ tridsať    }\\
    $2$  & {dva      }  &       $12$  &    { dvanásť  }   & $40$    &{ štyridsať  }\\   
    $3$  & {tri      }  &       $13$  &    { trinásť  }   & $50$    &{ päťdesiat   }\\
    $4$  & {štyri    }  &       $14$  &    { štrnásť}     & $60$    &{ šesťdesiat  }\\
    $5$  & {päť      }  &       $15$  &    { pätnásť  }   & $70$    &{ sedemdesiat } \\
    $6$  & {šesť     }  &       $16$  &    { šestnásť }   & $80$    &{ osemdesiat  } \\
    $7$  & {sedem    }  &       $17$  &    { sedemnásť}   & $90$    &{ deväťdesiat } \\
    $8$  & {osem     }  &       $18$  &    { osemnásť }   & $100$   &{ sto          }  \\
    $9$  & {deväť }  &          $19$  &    { devätnásť}\\
    $10$ & {desať }  &          $20$  &    { dvadsať }\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}}

\item 

  \begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{rl}
    \toprule  
        $21$ & {\sffamily twenty-one}\\
        $33$ & {\sffamily thirty-three}\\
        $9$  & {\sffamily nine}\\
        $55$ & {\sffamily fifty-five}\\
     \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table}

\end{itemize}  

%************************************************************
\newpage
%************************************************************

\section*{\foreignlanguage{slovak}{Radové číslovky}}



\begin{itemize}

\item  
  \begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{rllrl}
    \toprule
    { $1^{st}$} & {\sffamily the first}   & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress f3:st}]}          } & $1.$ \\
    { $2^{nd}$} & {\sffamily the second}  & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress sek.\super @nd}]} } & $2.$  \\  
    { $3^{rd}$} & {\sffamily the third}   & { \textsl{[\textipa{T3:d}]}                           } & $3.$  \\
    { $4^{th}$} & {\sffamily the fourth}  & { \textsl{[\textipa{fO:T}]}                           } & $4.$  \\
    { $5^{th}$} & {\sffamily the fifth}   & { \textsl{[\textipa{fIfT}]}                           } & $5.$   \\
    { $6^{th}$} & {\sffamily the sixth}   & { \textsl{[\textipa{sIksT}]}                          } & $6.$   \\
    { $7^{th}$} & {\sffamily the seventh} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress sev.\super @nT}]} } & $7.$   \\
    { $8^{th}$} & {\sffamily the eighth}  & { \textsl{[\textipa{eItT}]}                           } & $8.$    \\
    { $9^{th}$} & {\sffamily the ninth}   & { \textsl{[\textipa{naInT}]}                          } & $9.$   \\
    { $10^{th}$}& {\sffamily the tenth}  & { \textsl{[\textipa{tenT}]}                            } & $10.$  \\
    \bottomrule
    { $11^{th}$} & {\sffamily the eleventh}    & { \textsl{[\textipa{I\textprimstress lev.\super @nT}]}                    } & $11.$ \\
    { $12^{th}$} & {\sffamily the twelfth}     & { \textsl{[\textipa{twelfT}]}                                             } & $12.$ \\ 
    { $13^{th}$} & {\sffamily the thirteenth}  & { \textsl{[\textipa{T3:\textprimstress ti:.nT}]}                          } & $13.$ \\
    { $14^{th}$} & {\sffamily the fourteenth}  & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textsecstress fO:\textprimstress ti:.nT}]}           } & $14.$  \\
    { $15^{th}$} & {\sffamily the fifteenth}   & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textsecstress fIf\textprimstress ti:nT}]}            } & $15.$ \\
    { $16^{th}$} & {\sffamily the sixteenth}   & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textsecstress sIks\textprimstress ti:nT}]}           } & $16.$  \\
    { $17^{th}$} & {\sffamily the seventeenth} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textsecstress sev.\super @n\textprimstress ti:nT}]}  } & $17.$  \\
    { $18^{th}$} & {\sffamily the eighteenth}  & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textsecstress eI\textprimstress t:nT}]}              } & $18.$  \\
    { $19^{th}$} & {\sffamily the nineteenth}  & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textsecstress naIn\textprimstress ti:nT}]}           } & $19.$  \\
    { $20^{th}$} & {\sffamily the twentieth}   & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress twen.ti@T}]}                          } & $20.$  \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table} 

 \item  
  \begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{rllr}
    \toprule  
    { $30^{th}$} & { \sffamily the thirtieth}    & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress T3:.ti.@T}]}           }& $30.$  \\
    { $40^{th}$} & { \sffamily the fortieth}     & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress fO:.ti.@T}]}           }& $40.$  \\  
    { $50^{th}$} & { \sffamily the fiftieth}     & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress fIf.ti.@T}]}           }& $50.$  \\
    { $60^{th}$} & { \sffamily the sixtieth}     & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress sIk.sti.@T}]}          }& $60.$  \\
    { $70^{th}$} & { \sffamily the seventieth}   & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress sev.@n.ti.@T}]}}& $70.$   \\
    { $80^{th}$} & { \sffamily the eightieth}    & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress eI.ti.@T}]}            }& $80.$   \\
    { $90^{th}$} & { \sffamily the ninetieth}    & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress naIn.ti.@T}]}          }& $90.$   \\
    { $100^{th}$} & {\sffamily the hundredth}   & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress h2n.dr@th}]}           }& $100.$   \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table}

  \item  
  \scalebox{0.8}{
  \begin{tabular}{rlrlrl}
    \toprule    
    $1.$  & {prvý    }  &       $11.$  &    { jedenásty }   & $30.$    &{ tridsiaty    }\\
    $2.$  & {druhý   }  &       $12.$  &    { dvanásty  }   & $40.$    &{ štyridsiaty  }\\  
    $3.$  & {tretí   }  &       $13.$  &    { trinásty  }   & $50.$    &{ päťdesiaty   }\\
    $4.$  & {štvrtý  }  &       $14.$  &    { štvrtnásty}   & $60.$    &{ šesťdesiaty  }\\
    $5.$  & {piaty   }  &       $15.$  &    { pätnásty  }   & $70.$    &{ sedemdesiaty } \\
    $6.$  & {šiesty  }  &       $16.$  &    { šestnásty }   & $80.$    &{ osemdesiaty  } \\
    $7.$  & {siedmy  }  &       $17.$  &    { sedemnásty}   & $90.$    &{ deväťdesiaty } \\
    $8.$  & {ôsmy    }  &       $18.$  &    { osemnásty }   & $100.$   &{ stý          }  \\
    $9.$  & {deviaty }  &       $19.$  &    { devetnásty}\\
    $10.$ & {desiaty }  &       $20.$  &    { dvadsiaty }\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}}

\item 
  \begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{rl}
    \toprule  
        $21^{st}$ & {\sffamily the twenty-first}\\
        $33^{rd}$ & {\sffamily the thirty-third}\\
        $9^{th}$  & {\sffamily the ninth}\\
        $55^{th}$ & {\sffamily the fifty-fifth}\\
     \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove the `table` environments around the `tabular` (together with `\centering`)

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: I'm inclined to think that the loading of `babel` should be `\usepackage[english,main=slovak]{babel}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- First and foremost, get rid of all `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}` statements.
- If you want to top-align the `tabular` environments with the respective text-bullet symbols, replace all instances of `begin{tabular}...` with `\begin{tabular}[t]...`.
- Use `\textsuperscript{...}` instead of `^{...}`.
- You don't need any of the 352 [!] `$` symbols -- delete them as well.
- Instead of providing lots and lots (and lots...) of `\textsf` and `\textsl` directives in a multitude of cells, define the respective columns to use `>{\sffamily}` and `\slshape`, respectively.
- Use `\raggedbottom` in the preamble.

Aside: Are the text-bullet symbols even needed? Can they be omitted?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{book}
\usepackage[main=english,slovak]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tipa,array,booktabs,graphicx,lmodern}
\raggedbottom
\catcode`\-=12
\sloppy
\begin{document}

\section*{\foreignlanguage{slovak}{Číslovky}}

\begin{itemize}

\item ak je \textit{číslovka s podstatným menom} je \textit{jeden prízvuk}, na prvej slabike. Ak číslovka stojí na \textit{konci vety} bez podstatného mena, \textit{prízvuk} je na \textsf{-teen}. 

\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
    \toprule
    \textsf{She is \textbf{fifteen}.}   & 
    \textsf{\textbf{Fifteen} players play football.}\\ 
    \slshape [\textipa{fIf.\textprimstress ti:n}] & 
    \slshape [\textipa{\textprimstress fIf.ti:n}] \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}


\item \centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{r >{\sffamily}l >{\slshape}l r}
  \toprule
  1 & one & [\textipa{w2n}] & 1 \\
  2 & two & [\textipa{tu:}] & 2 \\  
  3 & three&[\textipa{Tri:}] & 3 \\
  4 & four &[\textipa{fO:\super r}] & 4\\
  5 & five & [\textipa{faIv}] & 5   \\
  6 & six  & [\textipa{sIks}] & 6   \\
  7 & seven& [\textipa{\textprimstress sev.@n}] & 7   \\
  8 & eight& [\textipa{eIt}] & 8    \\
  9 & nine & [\textipa{naIn}]& 9   \\
  10& ten  & [\textipa{ten}] & 10  \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\item   \centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{r >{\sffamily}l >{\slshape}l r}
\toprule    
11 & eleven   & [\textipa{I\textprimstress lev.@n}] & 11 \\
12 & twelve   & [\textipa{twelv}]                    & 12 \\  
13 & thirteen & [\textipa{T3:\textprimstress ti:.n}] & 13 \\
14 & fourteen & [\textipa{\textsecstress fO:\textprimstress ti:.n}] & 14  \\
15 & fifteen  & [\textipa{\textsecstress fIf\textprimstress ti:n}]  & 15 \\
16 & sixteen  & [\textipa{\textsecstress sIks\textprimstress ti:n}] & 16  \\
17 & seventeen& [\textipa{\textsecstress sev.\super @n\textprimstress ti:n}] & 17  \\
18 & eighteen & [\textipa{\textsecstress eI\textprimstress ti:n}]   & 18  \\
19 & nineteen & [\textipa{\textsecstress naIn\textprimstress ti:n}] & 19 \\
20 & twenty   & [\textipa{\textprimstress twen.ti}] & 20  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\item \centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{r >{\sffamily}l >{\slshape}l r}
\toprule  
   30 & thirty    & [\textipa{\textprimstress T3:.ti}] & 30  \\
   40 & forty     & [\textipa{\textprimstress fO:.ti}] & 40  \\   
   50 & fifty     & [\textipa{\textprimstress fIf.ti}] & 50  \\
   60 & sixty     & [\textipa{\textprimstress sIk.sti}] & 60  \\
   70 & seventy   & [\textipa{\textprimstress sev.@n.ti}] & 70   \\
   80 & eighty    & [\textipa{\textprimstress eI.ti}]    & 80   \\
   90 & ninety    & [\textipa{\textprimstress naIn.ti}]  & 90   \\
  100 & hundred   & [\textipa{\textprimstress h2n.dr@d}] & 100   \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\item \centering \scalebox{0.8}{%
\begin{tabular}[t]{rlrlrl}
  \toprule    
    1  &jeden  & 11  & jedenásť & 30    & tridsať    \\
    2  &dva    & 12  & dvanásť  & 40    & štyridsať  \\   
    3  &tri    & 13  & trinásť  & 50    & päťdesiat  \\
    4  &štyri  & 14  & štrnásť  & 60    & šesťdesiat \\
    5  &päť    & 15  & pätnásť  & 70    & sedemdesiat\\
    6  &šesť   & 16  & šestnásť & 80    & osemdesiat \\
    7  &sedem  & 17  & sedemnásť & 90   & deväťdesiat\\
    8  &osem   & 18  & osemnásť  & 100  & sto        \\
    9  &deväť  & 19  & devätnásť \\
    10 &desať  & 20  & dvadsať   \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}}

\item \centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{r >{\sffamily}l }
    \toprule  
        21 & twenty-one  \\
        33 & thirty-three\\
        9  & nine        \\
        55 & fifty-five  \\
     \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{itemize}  

\newpage

\section*{\foreignlanguage{slovak}{Radové číslovky}}

\begin{itemize}

\item \centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{r >{\sffamily}l >{\slshape}l r}
\toprule
   1\textsuperscript{st} &the first   & [\textipa{\textprimstress f3:st}]          & 1. \\
   2\textsuperscript{nd} &the second  & [\textipa{\textprimstress sek.\super @nd}] & 2.  \\  
   3\textsuperscript{rd} &the third   & [\textipa{T3:d}]                           & 3.  \\
   4\textsuperscript{th} &the fourth  & [\textipa{fO:T}]                           & 4.  \\
   5\textsuperscript{th} &the fifth   & [\textipa{fIfT}]                           & 5.   \\
   6\textsuperscript{th} &the sixth   & [\textipa{sIksT}]                          & 6.   \\
   7\textsuperscript{th} &the seventh & [\textipa{\textprimstress sev.\super @nT}] & 7.   \\
   8\textsuperscript{th} &the eighth  & [\textipa{eItT}]                           & 8.    \\
   9\textsuperscript{th} &the ninth   & [\textipa{naInT}]                          & 9.   \\
   10\textsuperscript{th}&the tenth   & [\textipa{tenT}]                            & 10.  \\
\midrule
   11\textsuperscript{th} &the eleventh    & [\textipa{I\textprimstress lev.\super @nT}]          & 11. \\
   12\textsuperscript{th} &the twelfth     & [\textipa{twelfT}]                                  & 12. \\ 
   13\textsuperscript{th} &the thirteenth  & [\textipa{T3:\textprimstress ti:.nT}]              & 13. \\
   14\textsuperscript{th} &the fourteenth  & [\textipa{\textsecstress fO:\textprimstress ti:.nT}] & 14.  \\
   15\textsuperscript{th} &the fifteenth   & [\textipa{\textsecstress fIf\textprimstress ti:nT}]  & 15. \\
   16\textsuperscript{th} &the sixteenth   & [\textipa{\textsecstress sIks\textprimstress ti:nT}] & 16.  \\
   17\textsuperscript{th} &the seventeenth & [\textipa{\textsecstress sev.\super @n\textprimstress ti:nT}] & 17.  \\
   18\textsuperscript{th} &the eighteenth  & [\textipa{\textsecstress eI\textprimstress t:nT}]    & 18.  \\
   19\textsuperscript{th} &the nineteenth  & [\textipa{\textsecstress naIn\textprimstress ti:nT}] & 19.  \\
   20\textsuperscript{th} &the twentieth   & [\textipa{\textprimstress twen.ti@T}]                & 20.  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 

\item  \centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{r >{\sffamily}l >{\slshape}l r}
   \toprule  
   30\textsuperscript{th} &the thirtieth    & [\textipa{\textprimstress T3:.ti.@T}] & 30.  \\
   40\textsuperscript{th} &the fortieth     & [\textipa{\textprimstress fO:.ti.@T}] & 40.  \\  
   50\textsuperscript{th} &the fiftieth     & [\textipa{\textprimstress fIf.ti.@T}] & 50.  \\
   60\textsuperscript{th} &the sixtieth     & [\textipa{\textprimstress sIk.sti.@T} & 60.  \\
   70\textsuperscript{th} &the seventieth   & [\textipa{\textprimstress sev.@n.ti.@T}]& 70.   \\
   80\textsuperscript{th} &the eightieth    & [\textipa{\textprimstress eI.ti.@T}] & 80.   \\
   90\textsuperscript{th} &the ninetieth    & [\textipa{\textprimstress naIn.ti.@T}]& 90.  \\
   100\textsuperscript{th} &the hundredth   & [\textipa{\textprimstress h2n.dr@th}] & 100. \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\item\scalebox{0.8}{
\begin{tabular}[t]{rlrlrl}
  \toprule    
  1.  &prvý    & 11.  & jedenásty & 30. & tridsiaty    \\
  2.  &druhý   & 12.  & dvanásty  & 40. & štyridsiaty  \\  
  3.  &tretí   & 13.  & trinásty  & 50. & päťdesiaty   \\
  4.  &štvrtý  & 14.  & štvrtnásty& 60. & šesťdesiaty  \\
  5.  &piaty   & 15.  & pätnásty  & 70. & sedemdesiaty \\
  6.  &šiesty  & 16.  & šestnásty & 80. & osemdesiaty  \\
  7.  &siedmy  & 17.  & sedemnásty& 90. & deväťdesiaty \\
  8.  &ôsmy    & 18.  & osemnásty & 100.& stý          \\
  9.  &deviaty & 19.  & devetnásty\\
  10. &desiaty & 20.  & dvadsiaty \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}}

\item \centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{r >{\sffamily}l }
    \toprule  
        21\textsuperscript{st} &the twenty-first\\
        33\textsuperscript{rd} &the thirty-third\\
        9\textsuperscript{th}  &the ninth\\
        55\textsuperscript{th} &the fifty-fifth\\
     \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Finally, here's a screenshot showing the first two pages of the typeset document:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Don't put your tables in a floating environment if you don't want them to float! Here is a solution, similar to my answer to one of your previous posts:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english,slovak]{babel}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[a6paper, top=10mm, left=10mm, right=10mm,
bottom=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}
\catcode`\-=12
\sloppy

%************************************************************
\newpage
%************************************************************
\section*{\foreignlanguage{slovak}{Číslovky}}

\begin{itemize}
  \item ak je \textit{číslovka s podstatným menom} je \textit{jeden prízvuk}, na prvej slabike. Ak číslovka stojí na \textit{konci vety} bez podstatného mena, \textit{prízvuk} je na {\sffamily -teen}.

  \begin{tabular}{@{\,}ll@{\,}}
    \toprule
    {\sffamily She is \textbf{fifteen}.} & {\sffamily \textbf{Fifteen} players play football.}\\
    \textsl{[\textipa{fIf.\textprimstress ti:n}]} & \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress fIf.ti:n}]} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}


\item \raisebox{1\baselineskip}[8ex]{\parbox[t]{\the\dimexpr\linewidth-\itemindent\relax}{\centering
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}rllrl@{}}
    \toprule
    { $1$} & {\sffamily one} & { \textsl{[\textipa{w2n}]} } & $1$ \\
    { $2$} & {\sffamily two} & { \textsl{[\textipa{tu:}]} } & $2$ \\
    { $3$} & {\sffamily three} & { \textsl{[\textipa{Tri:}]} } & $3$ \\
    { $4$} & {\sffamily four} & { \textsl{[\textipa{fO:\super r}]} } & $4$ \\
    { $5$} & {\sffamily five} & { \textsl{[\textipa{faIv}]} } & $5$ \\
    { $6$} & {\sffamily six} & { \textsl{[\textipa{sIks}]} } & $6$ \\
    { $7$} & {\sffamily seven} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress sev.@n}]} } & $7$ \\
    { $8$} & {\sffamily eight} & { \textsl{[\textipa{eIt}]} } & $8$ \\
    { $9$} & {\sffamily nine} & { \textsl{[\textipa{naIn}]} } & $9$ \\
   { $10$} & {\sffamily ten} & { \textsl{[\textipa{ten}]} } & $10$ \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  }}

  \item  \raisebox{1\baselineskip}{\parbox[t]{\the\dimexpr\linewidth-\itemindent\relax}{\centering
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}rllrl@{}}
    \toprule
    { $11$} & {\sffamily eleven} & { \textsl{[\textipa{I\textprimstress lev.@n}]} } & $11$ \\
    { $12$} & {\sffamily twelve} & { \textsl{[\textipa{twelv}]} } & $12$ \\
    { $13$} & {\sffamily thirteen} & { \textsl{[\textipa{T3:\textprimstress ti:.n}]} } & $13$ \\
    { $14$} & {\sffamily fourteen} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textsecstress fO:\textprimstress ti:.n}]} } & $14$ \\
    { $15$} & {\sffamily fifteen} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textsecstress fIf\textprimstress ti:n}]} } & $15$ \\
    { $16$} & {\sffamily sixteen} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textsecstress sIks\textprimstress ti:n}]} } & $16$ \\
    { $17$} & {\sffamily seventeen} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textsecstress sev.\super @n\textprimstress ti:n}]} } & $17$ \\
    { $18$} & {\sffamily eighteen} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textsecstress eI\textprimstress ti:n}]} } & $18$ \\
    { $19$} & {\sffamily nineteen} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textsecstress naIn\textprimstress ti:n}]} } & $19$ \\
    { $20$} & {\sffamily twenty} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress twen.ti}]} } & $20$ \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
 }}

  \item  \raisebox{1\baselineskip}[4.8ex]{\parbox[t]{\the\dimexpr\linewidth-\itemindent\relax}{%
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}rllr@{\,}}
    \toprule
    { $30$} & {\sffamily thirty} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress T3:.ti}]} }& $30$ \\
    { $40$} & {\sffamily forty} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress fO:.ti}]} }& $40$ \\
    { $50$} & {\sffamily fifty} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress fIf.ti}]} }& $50$ \\
    { $60$} & {\sffamily sixty} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress sIk.sti}]} }& $60$ \\
    { $70$} & {\sffamily seventy} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress sev.@n.ti}]}}& $70$ \\
    { $80$} & {\sffamily eighty} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress eI.ti}]} }& $80$ \\
    { $90$} & {\sffamily ninety} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress naIn.ti}]} }& $90$ \\
   { $100$} & {\sffamily hundred} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress h2n.dr@d}]} }& $100$ \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
}}

\item  \raisebox{1\baselineskip}[4.8ex]{\parbox[t]{\the\dimexpr\linewidth-\itemindent\relax}{%
\centering
  \scalebox{0.8}{
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{\,}rlrlrl@{\,}}
    \toprule
    $1$ & {jeden } & $11$ & { jedenásť } & $30$ &{ tridsať }\\
    $2$ & {dva } & $12$ & { dvanásť } & $40$ &{ štyridsať }\\
    $3$ & {tri } & $13$ & { trinásť } & $50$ &{ päťdesiat }\\
    $4$ & {štyri } & $14$ & { štrnásť} & $60$ &{ šesťdesiat }\\
    $5$ & {päť } & $15$ & { pätnásť } & $70$ &{ sedemdesiat } \\
    $6$ & {šesť } & $16$ & { šestnásť } & $80$ &{ osemdesiat } \\
    $7$ & {sedem } & $17$ & { sedemnásť} & $90$ &{ deväťdesiat } \\
    $8$ & {osem } & $18$ & { osemnásť } & $100$ &{ sto } \\
    $9$ & {deväť } & $19$ & { devätnásť}\\
    $10$ & {desať } & $20$ & { dvadsať }\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}}
  }}

\item  \raisebox{1\baselineskip}{\parbox[t]{\the\dimexpr\linewidth-\itemindent\relax}{%
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{\,}rl@{\,}}
    \toprule
        $21$ & {\sffamily twenty-one}\\
        $33$ & {\sffamily thirty-three}\\
        $9$ & {\sffamily nine}\\
        $55$ & {\sffamily fifty-five}\\
     \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  }}

\end{itemize}

%************************************************************
\newpage
%************************************************************

\section*{\foreignlanguage{slovak}{Radové číslovky}}

\begin{itemize}

\item  \raisebox{1\baselineskip}[8ex]{\parbox[t]{\the\dimexpr\linewidth-\itemindent\relax}{%
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}rllrl@{}}
    \toprule
    { $1^{st}$} & {\sffamily the first} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress f3:st}]} } & $1.$ \\
    { $2^{nd}$} & {\sffamily the second} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress sek.\super @nd}]} } & $2.$ \\
    { $3^{rd}$} & {\sffamily the third} & { \textsl{[\textipa{T3:d}]} } & $3.$ \\
    { $4^{th}$} & {\sffamily the fourth} & { \textsl{[\textipa{fO:T}]} } & $4.$ \\
    { $5^{th}$} & {\sffamily the fifth} & { \textsl{[\textipa{fIfT}]} } & $5.$ \\
    { $6^{th}$} & {\sffamily the sixth} & { \textsl{[\textipa{sIksT}]} } & $6.$ \\
    { $7^{th}$} & {\sffamily the seventh} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress sev.\super @nT}]} } & $7.$ \\
    { $8^{th}$} & {\sffamily the eighth} & { \textsl{[\textipa{eItT}]} } & $8.$ \\
    { $9^{th}$} & {\sffamily the ninth} & { \textsl{[\textipa{naInT}]} } & $9.$ \\
    { $10^{th}$}& {\sffamily the tenth} & { \textsl{[\textipa{tenT}]} } & $10.$ \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    { $11^{th}$} & {\sffamily the eleventh} & { \textsl{[\textipa{I\textprimstress lev.\super @nT}]} } & $11.$ \\
    { $12^{th}$} & {\sffamily the twelfth} & { \textsl{[\textipa{twelfT}]} } & $12.$ \\
    { $13^{th}$} & {\sffamily the thirteenth} & { \textsl{[\textipa{T3:\textprimstress ti:.nT}]} } & $13.$ \\
    { $14^{th}$} & {\sffamily the fourteenth} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textsecstress fO:\textprimstress ti:.nT}]} } & $14.$ \\
    { $15^{th}$} & {\sffamily the fifteenth} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textsecstress fIf\textprimstress ti:nT}]} } & $15.$ \\
    { $16^{th}$} & {\sffamily the sixteenth} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textsecstress sIks\textprimstress ti:nT}]} } & $16.$ \\
    { $17^{th}$} & {\sffamily the seventeenth} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textsecstress sev.\super @n\textprimstress ti:nT}]} } & $17.$ \\
    { $18^{th}$} & {\sffamily the eighteenth} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textsecstress eI\textprimstress t:nT}]} } & $18.$ \\
    { $19^{th}$} & {\sffamily the nineteenth} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textsecstress naIn\textprimstress ti:nT}]} } & $19.$ \\
    { $20^{th}$} & {\sffamily the twentieth} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress twen.ti@T}]} } & $20.$ \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  }}

 \item  \raisebox{1\baselineskip}[8ex]{\parbox[t]{\the\dimexpr\linewidth-\itemindent\relax}{%
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}rllr@{}}
    \toprule
    { $30^{th}$} & { \sffamily the thirtieth} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress T3:.ti.@T}]} }& $30.$ \\
    { $40^{th}$} & { \sffamily the fortieth} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress fO:.ti.@T}]} }& $40.$ \\
    { $50^{th}$} & { \sffamily the fiftieth} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress fIf.ti.@T}]} }& $50.$ \\
    { $60^{th}$} & { \sffamily the sixtieth} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress sIk.sti.@T}]} }& $60.$ \\
    { $70^{th}$} & { \sffamily the seventieth} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress sev.@n.ti.@T}]}}& $70.$ \\
    { $80^{th}$} & { \sffamily the eightieth} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress eI.ti.@T}]} }& $80.$ \\
    { $90^{th}$} & { \sffamily the ninetieth} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress naIn.ti.@T}]} }& $90.$ \\
    { $100^{th}$} & {\sffamily the hundredth} & { \textsl{[\textipa{\textprimstress h2n.dr@th}]} }& $100.$ \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  }}

  \item  \raisebox{1\baselineskip}[8ex]{\parbox[t]{\the\dimexpr\linewidth-\itemindent\relax}{%
  \centering
  \scalebox{0.8}{
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}rlrlrl@{}}
    \toprule
    $1.$ & {prvý } & $11.$ & { jedenásty } & $30.$ &{ tridsiaty }\\
    $2.$ & {druhý } & $12.$ & { dvanásty } & $40.$ &{ štyridsiaty }\\
    $3.$ & {tretí } & $13.$ & { trinásty } & $50.$ &{ päťdesiaty }\\
    $4.$ & {štvrtý } & $14.$ & { štvrtnásty} & $60.$ &{ šesťdesiaty }\\
    $5.$ & {piaty } & $15.$ & { pätnásty } & $70.$ &{ sedemdesiaty } \\
    $6.$ & {šiesty } & $16.$ & { šestnásty } & $80.$ &{ osemdesiaty } \\
    $7.$ & {siedmy } & $17.$ & { sedemnásty} & $90.$ &{ deväťdesiaty } \\
    $8.$ & {ôsmy } & $18.$ & { osemnásty } & $100.$ &{ stý } \\
    $9.$ & {deviaty } & $19.$ & { devetnásty}\\
    $10.$ & {desiaty } & $20.$ & { dvadsiaty }\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}}
  }}

\item  \raisebox{1\baselineskip}[8ex]{\parbox[t]{\the\dimexpr\linewidth-\itemindent\relax}{%
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}[t]{rl}
    \toprule
        $21^{st}$ & {\sffamily the twenty-first}\\
        $33^{rd}$ & {\sffamily the thirty-third}\\
        $9^{th}$ & {\sffamily the ninth}\\
        $55^{th}$ & {\sffamily the fifty-fifth}\\
     \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
 }}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]